# ClassNotFoundException - Makes No Sense

Tags: java, class, jar

### General Information

I am developing a plugin for Minecraft using Bukkit's API.
I have to use Apache Commons NET library.

#### The Problem

I am getting a ClassNotFoundException once the JAR is run.

#### Resolution (RESOLVED)

I manually made my MANIFEST.MF file (set it to use my custom file when exporting the JAR) and put this inside of it:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: libs/commons-net-3.0.1.jar
```

Worked like a charm.

---

### What I've Done

I created a folder in the Project Explorer within my plugin and named it "libs". I copied the .jar for the Apache Commons library into said folder.

I then right clicked my project, went to Java Build Path, Add JAR(s), MyPlugin > libs > `the.jar`

Once added, everything from within the coding works fine. All imports are read correctly and no issue arises.

Upon exporting the project, it is noticeably larger as the library is attached to the .jar

#### However

I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient
at me.geekplaya.AdventureLobbies.FileUpload.upload(FileUpload.java:14)
at me.geekplaya.AdventureLobbies.AdventureLobbies.onCommand(AdventureLobbies.java:766)
at org.bukkit.command.PluginCommand.execute(PluginCommand.java:40)
... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:41)
at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:29)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
... 15 more
```

---

## Screenshots

[image]
[image]

---

.classpath

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/gray/Applications/Java Workspace/Server/craftbukkit.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/commons-net-3.0.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: You say, the plugin file is a bit larger because the library is packed into it, but how do you know that the API is actually reading the contents of the JAR and loading it into the classloader along your own classes? You may need to check that API's documentation.

Comment: Your image is too messed up to make sense of. Perhaps post the XML content of your .classpath file? Are you launching from Eclipse or a command line? If from command line, adding jars to the classpath is a separate requirement.

Comment: The Build path is the path used to *build* the app. You have a problem when *running* the app. How do you run it? How do you set the classpath when running the app? Note that jars containing jars is non-standard, and will only work using a special class loader. Your jar and the commons net jar should both be in the classpath when running the app.

Comment: My guess you need to add other dependency jars from commons.

Comment: I have updated the post, tell me what you think now.

Comment: This could help you - http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html

Answer (score 3):

You want to scrutinize that stacktrace.  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError is not java.lang.ClassNotFoundException.  I think it is finding all the classes that are in the commons-net-3.0.1.jar but commons-net-3.0.1.jar has some dependency that is not being met.  Crack the commons-net-3.0.1.jar open and see if you can locate a .class to satisfy the org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.  If its not in there, you'll have to find out where it comes from (probably some other JAR) and get it on the classpath as well.

Comment: The JB Nizet comment above may hold some clue as well.  Googling around, it looks like the org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient is part of Commons Net 3.0.1 API.  This makes my answer not really applicable to your issue.

Comment: The FTPClient *should* be there: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcommonsnet301jar.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you notice the line:

```
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
```

This is a line that is loading a class using reflection.  Try to go to the source in your stack trace and find what class it is trying to load.

Comment: Can you expand on this now that I have organized my question?

Answer (score -2):

im not a pro, but i would think you have to add it to the classpath.if you have already done that then the path to the c